# How to insert specific character in penultimate index of string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to insert a hyphen `-` in the penultimate index of string.

I created a code in javascript using `substring()` that works:

```
let str = "mystring";
let size = str.length;
let lastCaracter = str.substring(size - 1, size);
let newStr = str.substring(0, size - 1);

newStr = newStr + "-" + lastCaracter;
```

but I think it's cleanner with regex, so how can I convert this code to regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple methods, with and without regex. I'm not sure I agree that regex is cleaner, so I'll leave that up to you.

Having said that, caching the length with `let size = str.length;` is a questionable practice. Just access  `.length` directly, which eliminates confusion about what `size` refers to and avoids bugs when the variable's length changes but you forget to update the cached copy.

```js
const str = "mystring";
const hyphenated = `${str.slice(0, -1)}-${str.slice(-1)}`;

console.log(hyphenated);
```

```js
const str = "mystring";
const hyphenated = str.replace(/(.)$/, "-$1");

console.log(hyphenated);
```

Comment: The first option is better and cleanner! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`\w` will capture any word character, and `$` selects the position at the end of that selection

`$1` is a backreference to the selection we had in the regex, and we add a `-` before this

```js
console.log("myString".replace(/(\w)$/, "-$1"))
```